# Show record of logged in user in laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, forms

I want to show a list of complaint of a logged-in user how would I write if else in a blade.

```
@foreach($data as $row)

        <tr>
            <td>{{ $row->type }}</td>
            <td>{{ $row->station }}</td>
            <td>{{ $row->description }}</td>
            <td>{{ $row->comment }} </td>
            <td>{{ $row->status }}</td>

            <td class="text-center">
                <a href="{{ route('view-complaint', $row->id) }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-eye mr-1" aria-hidden="true"></i>Show</a>
                <a href="{{ route('edit-complaint', $row->id) }}" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-pencil mr-1" aria-hidden="true"></i>Edit</a>
                <form action="{{ route('delete-complaint', $row->id) }}" method="post" class="d-inline-block">
                    @csrf
                    @method('DELETE')
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-trash mr-1" aria-hidden="true"></i>Delete</button>
                </form>
            </td>

        </tr>

        @endforeach
```

and this my index function, it also works for admin to show all complaints of all users. But I want the complaints for a specific user who logged in. I mean the user can see all of his complaints

```
public function index()
    {
        $data = Complaint::latest()->paginate(5);
        return view('pages.allComplaints', compact('data'))->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
    }
```

How would I handle this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the Index method like this:

```
public function index()
{
    if(auth()->user()){
        $data = Complaint::latest()->where('user_id',auth()->user()->id)->paginate(5);
    }else{
        $data = Complaint::latest()->paginate(5);
    }
    return view('pages.allComplaints', compact('data'))->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
}
```

Comment: I just make if this in if: if(auth()->user()->role=='USER') and its works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

You can try `if-else` in blade as mentioned below:

```
@if($user->logged_in)         
      //show records    
@else
      //not logged in    
@endif
```